# Dot product between relative velocity and relative position in orbital mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, satellites

Reading Curtis' book *Orbital Mechanics* I found this relation that confused me.

$$
\underline{r}\cdot\underline{\dot{r}}=r\dot{r}
$$

What happens, say, for a circular orbit where $\underline{r}$ and $\dot{\underline{r}}$ are orthogonal? Shouldn't the scalar product be zero?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Please, take into account that questions line "check my calculations" or 'hot to go from ea. "X" to eq. "y"' are considered *homework-like questions* and are at risk of been closed. Just as a hint, what would be $\dot r$ in the case of a uniform circular motion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be, and it is. On the right side of the equation, $\dot r$ is zero for a circular orbit, because $r$ is constant.